# Should i write my first fiction novel in the present or the past tense when writing in the first preson?

Tags: fiction, style

Im writing my first novel in the first person, and i cant decide if it sounds better (and if its easier) in the present or the past. Please help!

Comment: This seems identical to this question which is currently active: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/30061/is-it-better-the-use-the-present-or-the-past-tense-for-a-novel-written-in-the-fi

Comment: @TheNovelFactory Normally, we'd close the newer question as a duplicate of the older one. In this case, however, this question has no answers, and the newer question has several upvoted answers, which makes it a better duplicate target.

Comment: I was thinking this one should be deleted, but don't feel experienced on the forum enough yet to do something like that - if I even have the ability to do it. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: @TheNovelFactory Duplicates aren't bad per se; they can act as signposts to help people find their way around the site. If one user was having trouble finding a duplicate of what they were asking, it's quite possible that others may have similar trouble. Thus, generally speaking, it's not a good idea to delete legitimate questions that happen to be closed as duplicates.

Comment: Okay - thanks. I'll stick to a hands off approach until I'm very familiar with how everything works.